# Alternation with grep

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to use `grep` to capture files that contain one of the two sentences.

To capture one sentence I use

```
grep -L "Could not place marker for right window edge" *log
```

For two sentences, to see if either of them exists in the file I tried

```
grep -L "Could not place marker for right window edge \| Could not place marker for left window edge" *log
```

But this is not working.

Any advice on this?

Comment: is this question about grep or R?

Comment: You could "grep right *log" or "grep left *log"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the starting and trailing space you have introduced is causing the problem. Try:

```
$ egrep -L 'this is sentence|another different sentence' *log
```

Alternatively using `fgrep` as you are just looking for fixed strings and not regular expression:

```
$ fgrep -Le 'this is sentence' -e 'another different sentence' *log
```

If by sentence you actually mean line then you may also be interested in the `-x` argument.

> -x, --line-regexp
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line. (-x is specified by POSIX.)

You are using `-L` which displays the files without matches is this what you actually want or did you mean `-l` to display just the filenames that do match?

Answer (score 1):

Try this 3 [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) variations :

```
grep -l 'this is sentence\|another different sentence' *log
grep -lE 'this is sentence|another different sentence' *log
grep -lE '(this is sentence|another different sentence)' *log
```

If you want to find files that match, `-L` is not the right switch; instead use `-l`, from `man grep` :

```
-L, --files-without-match
Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file
from which no output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will
stop on the first match.

-l, --files-with-matches
Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which
output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first
match.  (-l is specified  by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thanks. i figured it out now. it was a space problem as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/Could not place marker for right window edge|Could not place marker for left window edge/' *.log
```

Or this could be done like this

```
awk '/Could not place marker for (right|left) window edge/' *.log
```